# Calculating PMF of X. An urn contains 4 red balls, 3 green balls, and 2 blue balls.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

An urn contains 4 red balls, 3 green balls, and 2 blue balls. You draw 3 balls without replacement. Let $X$ be the number of red balls drawn. What is the PMF of $X$?

How would I go about calculating this using the multinomial forumla?

Most solutions use the following method:

$\frac{\binom{3}{x} \times \binom{5}{3-x}}{\binom{9}{3}}$

However, there are similarities here with the multinomial. One can ask the question, what is the probability of obtaining 3 red balls. And you can find that out using:

$\frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!...k_i!}\times p_1k_1p_2k_2...p_ik_i$

How would I go about setting this up so I can solve it using the multinomial formula? Can it be solved this way? Or because its without replacement I cannot use the multinomial formula?

**ELI5 Please**

Comment: What are the $p_j$ in your multinomial?

Comment: The probability is easy to calculate. There are 9 balls in total. 4/9 is the probability of a red ball. So on and so forth. I think the reason why this might not work is because this is WITHOUT replacement. Once you draw one red ball, the probability of the red ball is no longer 4/9. It will be 3/8. At least so I am guessing.

Comment: Yes, your guess is right. The multinomial distribution, like the binomial distribution, needs to have constant probabilities for its elements. And btw, I suppose in the formula you wrote, you meant $p_1^{k_1}...$ and so on.

Comment: @trueblueanil well that answers that. I have been wondering why I could not solve it. lol.. Thanks!

Comment: For what its worth, you may treat green differently than blue if you like and keep track of three distinct categories... but it is easier to just treat them all as "*not-red*" and have only two categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The multinomial model will not work because it corresponds to sampling with replacement, just as how a binomial model would not work when sampling occurs without replacement.

The hypergeometric model is correct:  the probability mass function is

$$\Pr[X = x] = \frac{\binom{4}{x}\binom{5}{3-x}}{\binom{9}{3}}.$$  This is because there are $4$ red balls, of which there are $\binom{4}{x}$ ways to choose $x$ red balls in the sample; and $5$ non-red balls, of which there are $\binom{5}{3-x}$ ways to choose these.  These choices are independent, so the total number of ways to select $x$ red balls and $3-x$ non-red balls is their product $\binom{4}{x}\binom{5}{3-x}$.  Then we divide by the total number of ways to choose $3$ balls out of $9$ without regard to color.

The multinomial model would be applicable if we wanted to count the number of balls drawn of each color when, after each draw, the ball is replaced.  So for instance, we could ask for $X_r$ red balls, $X_g$ green balls, and $X_b$ blue balls when $n = X_r + X_g + X_b$ balls are sampled *with replacement*.  This would give the multivariate probably mass function

$$\Pr[(X_r, X_g, X_b) = (x_r, x_g, x_b)] = \frac{(x_r + x_g + x_b)!}{x_r! x_g! x_b!} p_r^{x_r} p_g^{x_g} p_b^{x_b},$$ where $p_r = 4/9$, $p_g = 3/9$, and $p_b = 2/9$ are the individual Bernoulli probabilities of drawing a red, green, and blue ball in a single trial, respectively.